# How do I use a "BroadcastContext" to call spawn_broadcast with Rayon?

Tags: multithreading, rust, rayon

I am new to Rust, and I am trying to understand the documentation for the Rayon library. I do not understand the prototype for or the definition of `spawn_broadcast`, and I also can't find an example of how to call this function. The manual reads:

```
source pub fn spawn_broadcast<OP>(&self, op: OP)
where
OP: Fn(BroadcastContext<'_>) + Send + Sync + 'static,
```

I don't know how to decipher this. I was able to figure out how to use `spawn` and `spawn_fifo` from looking at examples. Like this:

```
for i in 0..rayon::current_num_threads() {
  s.spawn(move |_s| {
    println!("Iteration {i}, thread {}",rayon::current_thread_index().unwrap());
  });
}
```

Does anyone know of an example of calling this method, or, can you explain what the definition means?

Comment: There are [3 methods `spawn_broadcast`](https://docs.rs/rayon/latest/rayon/struct.BroadcastContext.html?search=method%3Aspawn_broadcast) can you clarify which one you mean? None of them are implemented on `BroadcastContext` so you can't use one to `spawn_broadcast`.